# htaccess drop php for clean SEO friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, permalinks

I'm having trouble dropping the file extension of my webpages. I have a static site of around 10 php files. I do not have any query parameters in the url. I'd like to have SEO friendly urls.

mysite.com/other-errors instead of mysite.com/other-errors.php

I've been searching but none of the entries in my htaccess file are working. This is what i've tired, amongst other version:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I know I can go the other way:

```
RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]
```

But I'd have to do this for every php file, which is a little time consuming.  This must be possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved my problem I needed one of the other solutions
I tried  with my redirects. Is this the correct way?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

#Permalink
RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^e02-error e02-error.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^other-errors other-errors.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^setup-and-chemical-balance setup-and-chemical-balance.php [NC,L]
```